# Heroku declined payments. Support can't find the problem

Tags: heroku, payment, verify

I'm having a problem with payment procedure in heroku account(billing section).
I got verified first time successfully and in one month all charges of my card are giving an error: "Unable to verify your card. Please try later or contact your financial institution for help'".
I tried with 10 credit cards, all of which are from Mexico (and I triple checked all the info and I’m sure it’s correct). I also talked to my bank and there is no attempt of charging cards.

Heroku support can't help me out. This is their answer to my ticket "I truly wish I could be of more assistance, but unfortunately I do not have access to anything that would be able to make a difference here. I apologize for the poor experience."

Maybe someone had the same problem?
Thank you.

Comment: hi there, did you ever get this fixed? having the same issue

Comment: Hey John.. I moved to DigitalOcean. But you should create a ticket to support team and don't try to pay too many time as I did because payment system will block you forever.

Comment: thanks, they ultimately took care of this for me, for some reason it was triggering some fraud alerts.  i didn't get a response until i started complaining on facebook...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is ... that noone can help me in Heroku.

Support of Heroku answered: "Unfortunately, the many layers of security make it impossible for us to further investigate. I find it frustrating myself, since my job is to try and help customers and in cases like this I'm told there's nothing I can do. I'm truly sorry for the poor experience here. The only choices are pretty much to use only Free Dynos and no add-ons except the free version of Heroku Postgres (and no custom domains), or to move to a different platform. I apologize that these are really the only choices".

So I'm moving to other platform. Lol

Answer (score 3):

If that many cards are not working, one of the possibilities is that your user footprint (things that can compare your online activity to the other user profiles, like location, e-mail, credit card) could be triggering fraud prevention tools, which can happen if patterns are identified that are similar to ones used by spam or fraudulent accounts. It doesn't necessarily mean that your account is identified as fraudulent or spam, but it does mean that the virtual footprint is considered too risky to approve.

Comment: Could be... but I have no idea how to fix this problem. Nowhere I can clear my footprint.

Comment: It seems that heroku payment processing provider is blocking this transaction for some reason. Support should help you out.

Comment: They don't help... Their answer is "Unfortunately we have no inside tools that would help a declined card  by system be accepted"

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a VPN, try turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem today. Neighter Revolut or Wise card seemed to work. Once I've disconnect from my VPN adding card worked and the problem was solved.